# .apk file not running on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, flex-mobile, flash-builder4.5

I made a simple hello world basic program in flash builder (flex mobile project) and then converted it to .apk file using the "export release build" feature, In the end it packaged my app and then the dialog box closes, although i selected the option to install it on the available android emulator, But the app was not installed there.

Moreover when i try to install it through command prompt it gives me error "**failure [install_fail_invalid_apk]**".

I guess there will be nothing wrong in the code as i didn't change any thing in it except added a "hello world" lablel. It runs fine when i ran it as mobile application on flash builder. Kindly help me.

Comment: realease version has different key, uninstall debug version from device/emulator and install release then

Comment: can u plz explore more...i didn't get u.Thanks

Comment: but the app is not installing in my emulator. I went to settings>app> and there i don't see my app installed

Comment: you can use `keytool` to generate your certificate for release.